# JSON master-detail structure

Tags: json, structure, master-detail, invoice

I am trying to model a simple invoice that has an invoice object with minimally an ArrayList and an lineitem object with an ArrayList of the values for a given row.  I get my result-set, loop over it and every time create a new lineitem object, populate the lineitem ArrayList with the desired field values and then add that lineitem to the invoice ArrayList.  I then add this to a JSONArray and then "flatten" it with toString() to get my json string to send to the client.  The problem is all the lines are there but as a "bare" array of lineitem objects.  I need another structure that I can loop on client-side, access each lineitem object, and print the row to the screen and continue.  How do I structure it so I have and "outer" object that I can loop over to process the lineitems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "parse" the values / array on the server side to build up a string that can be interpreted as JSON on the client. There are lots of libraries (both server & client side that can help you with this). Ultimately you need a string that looks somthing like the following when it arrives on the client side.

```
var strJsonInvoive = "[InvoiceID : 1, Date : "01/01/1900", otherProperties: "value" ,
//the Invoice Detail Objects below will result in an array of objects
InvoiceDetails : [InvoiceDetailID : 1, Description: "desc", Price: 100, Quantity: 1, Tax: true],
[InvoiceDetailID : 2, Description: "desc", Price: 200, Quantity: 2, Tax: false],
[InvoiceDetailID : 3, Description: "desc", Price: 300, Quantity: 3, Tax: true]]";
```

At this point, the above is purely a string, so again, you need to Parse this client side to turn this into an object, for example you could use jQuery to Parse the json string as follows :

```
var jsonInvoice = jQuery.parseJSON(strJsonInvoice);
```

Now, you will have an object that you can work with as follows :

```
for(var 1=0; i<jsonInvoice.InvoiceDetails.length;i++)
{
    if (jsonInvoice.InvoiceDetails[i].Price > 50)
        //do something if price is greater than 50
}
```

Hope this helps.

Dave

Comment: Hi Dave 
Thank you for the precise detail, and I believe I understand it your way.  I am trying with less structure for speed and flexibility.  Can you help me understand why I cannot client-side parse the string I can produce below.  I want to be able to loop through "lineItem" and loop through the data in a given lineItem cant see how to structure the jscript.  I am using prototype should I switch to jQuery?  Again thank you.  

[{"invoice":[{"lineItem":[{"datum":1},{"datum":Shampoo},...]},{"lineItem":[{"datum":3},{"datum":Ajax Detergent},...]}...}]

Comment: Hi All
It was a syntax issue for me again.  I didnt convert the string to JSON.

Comment: @cp - no prob, glad you were able to get it sorted :-)